# Show/hide Bootstrap tab/pill based on range input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, range

Refer to my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azzaeff/y3sff3p2/2/) here.

I am using Bootstrap tabs on top, and the number of 'Menu' tabs revealed or hidden is depended on the range slider I put in the 'Home' tab. At the moment I am limiting it to 3 menu tabs, so if I drag the range slider to the right, the Menu tab will be revealed one by one until the slider reaches all the way to the end, which in this case is 3 tabs. The reverse is also true - dragging the slider to the left will hide the menu tab one by one until none. This works flawlessly.

```
$('#menutab').on('input', function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "1") {
        $("#menu1tab").show();
        $("#menu2tab").hide();
        $("#menu3tab").hide();
      } else if ($(this).val() === "2") {
        $("#menu1tab").show();
        $("#menu2tab").show();
        $("#menu3tab").hide();
      } else if ($(this).val() === "3") {
        $("#menu1tab").show();
        $("#menu2tab").show();
        $("#menu3tab").show();
      } else {
        $("#menu1tab").hide();
        $("#menu2tab").hide();
        $("#menu3tab").hide();
      }
    });
```

However, if I would like to expand the number of tab to, say, 20 tabs or more, then I have to write lots of `$("#menu**x**tab").show()` and `$("#menu**x**tab").hide()` repetitively, and I don't think that this is really efficient way of coding.

If anyone could write a shorter/more efficient way of doing this, I would be very grateful. Either in JS or JQ is okay for me.

Comment: As per your question from today, questions of the form "please improve this for me" are considered requests for free work here. Please keep your questions much more focussed.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap, class .hidden-(xs-sm-md-lg-xl)-up or .hidden-(xs-sm-md-lg-xl)-down

```
    ex:
   <div hidden-xs-up>
    </div>
```

u can view this div only on xs display

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/
oh sorry

```
for (i = 0; i < *munulong*; i++) { 
  ('#menutab').on('input', function() {
      if ($(this).val() === i) {
        $("#menu"+i+"tab").show();
      } else {
        $("#menu"+i+"tab").hide();
      } 
    });
}
```

I'm not sure, but if u want u can test it

Comment: Thanks @Gioggi, but I don't think this is applicable for my use. If you refer to my fiddle link above, you would understand what I am trying to achieve. But thanks anyway.

Comment: If u want test it i change the anwer

Comment: It doesn't work @Gioggi but it's ok, although I did thought about using loop as what you have attempted. I'll leave this to others if anyone else can improve on it.